# Firefox issue with relatively position divs causing body to scroll

Tags: html, css, firefox, dom

The markup below shows up in IE, Chrome, and Edge as expected. In Firefox it causes the body to have a gutter at the bottom of the page which is the same height as the blue div.

```html
    <html>
 <body style="background-color: red; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

  <div style="height: 100%"></div>

  <div style=" width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: blue; position: relative; top: -500px;"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The </html> tag got lost - sorry about that.

Comment: Can't reproduce here. What version of FF? Do you have any extensions/add-ons/plugins in FF?

Comment: Vanilla FF - I am suspicious this is a new FF bug as it suddenly popped up. Running version 76.0.1 (64-bit)